# F5 BIG-IP workaround to CVE-2020-5902 vulnerability

Tags: f5-big-ip, vulnerability

Do you have any idea of a workaround for the [CVE-2020-5902](https://app.howlermonkey.io/vulnerabilities/cve-2020-5902) vulnerability?

I cannot update at the moment, but I am concerned because it is a **Critical vulnerability**.

Comment: Did you click through to F5's support page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F5 seems to be digging themselves deeper and deeper with this issue. Their initial workaround didn't actually fix the issue. i get it, it happens. Then it turns out their second workaround didn't fix it either and their page now says there is no workaround at all. Sighh ... It really sucks for those who had to do overnight changes to implement these workarounds as all the work they have done is now useless, twice. Just know that lots of customers are in the same boat. Lots of giants use these appliances and it's not always viable to patch for big companies on such short notice.

The best you can do at this point is to make sure the management interface is not exposed to internet and hope your management doesn't mention the words "insider threat".